# Request sent successfully but not reflecting on friend profile

Tags: ios, facebook

```
// Display the requests dialog

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social." title:nil parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } 
     else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } 
         else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } 
             else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, requests won't show up in users wall/feed, but rather as notifications under the "globe" icon. However, requests won't show up in the notifications if:

1) The application is in Sandbox mode, and the receiver isn't a developer on the app. (any level)

2) The user has disabled requests for the app / notifications from FB. (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications)

From personal experience, I would also add that Facebook tends to not show notifications for requests if you spam them too much or if you have low rating for posts. (Check [facebook.com/insights](http://facebook.com/insights))